# How do you access an array in python from Java

Tags: java, python, jython

I want to do something like this:

Python Code:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
```

Java Code:

```
nums_Java[] = nums //from python
System.out.println(nums_Java[0])
```

Output:

```
1
```

I have been looking over jython but I just can't seem to find the answer. It seems like it should be very simple but I'm lost. Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing? You want to print whole array? In java its System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums_Java));

Comment: Sorry I named the array differently... The point of the print statement was to demonstrate that the array for nums_Java was the same as the array from python.

Comment: I don't think you understand what Jython is... Jython is the same as Python. It IS Python, just that the source code of the Python interpreter is in Java. You cannot mix Java and Python syntax...

Comment: it doesn't matter what the source code of the interpreter is written in, what really matters about jython is that it compiles python source code down to jvm bytecode.

Comment: @acushner That comment will probably add confusion. Jython does not compile anything. Jython is a language. The Jython *compiler* is what compiles Jython into JVM bytecode.

Comment: Is there a way to get a python variable from java without converting the python code into jython?

Comment: This might help: [Communication between Java and Python](http://wiki.danse.us/danse/index.php?title=Communication_between_Java_and_Python)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you'd like to run some embedded python code from a java program, and get the value of a python variable.

Based on http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/embedding.html , I wrote a small program that might help:

```
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter; 
import org.python.core.*; 

public class SimpleEmbedded { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PyException {
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
        interp.exec("nums = [1,2,3]");
        PyObject nums = interp.get("nums");
        System.out.println("nums: " + nums);
        System.out.println("nums is of type: " + nums.getClass());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't have jython installed at the moment, so the above code is untested. Also I'm not sure what type you will get back from the interpreter, and how to convert it to a java array or access its items. But the program should get you started and give you some more information.